# assigning List is thread safe in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I searched and found assigning object is thread safe(except long, double type)
I want to confirm following code is thread safe.

```
class SharedAnyClass {
 public static volatile obj = new ArrayList();
}

class Writer {
  // thread 1
  void run() {
     List temp = new ArrayList();
     temp.add(xx);
     SharedAnyClass.obj= temp;  // assign object in thread 1
  }
}

class Reader {
  void run() {
    List temp = SharedAnyClass.obj;
    for ( int i=0;i<temp.length(); i++ ) {
       temp.get(xx)... // read object in thread 2
    }      
 }
}
```

As I know, 
When Reader is reading shared List in for loop,
Writer thread can assign shared List in thread safe.
In this case, Reader thread still can read shared List in for loop with old shared List object.
When Reader thread try to execute run() function later, it will read new shared List object.
Is it right?

Comment: No. There is no guarantee the Reader thread will see the updated value, unless `obj` is declared `volatile`.

Comment: (the code isn't type-safe, either).

Comment: @AndyTurner When I declare SharedAnyClass.obj as volatile type, there is no problem? I edited my code ( adding volatile type)

Comment: Your code will *work* now, but both public fields and statics are a bad design (they're global variables, which cause all sorts of problems). You also risk lost updates if the writer runs more than once. The entire design would be much simpler with a `ConcurrentQueue` shared between the reader and writer (e.g., as a constructor parameter).

Comment: @AndyTurner cutting out bad design, why isn't it thread safe? `volatile` making sure the reference is safely published.

Comment: @SomeName OP edited the question adding the `volatile` after I mentioned it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is wrong. The line

> ```
> List temp = SharedAnyClass.obj;
> ```
>
> can occur before  the assignment
>
> ```
>  SharedAnyClass.obj= temp;  // assign object in thread 1
> ```
>
> and so would read the initial empty list.